# Need to sanitize <ng-include src="url"> but ng-bind-html wants an expression and doesn't accept URLs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include, ng-bind-html

I'm writing an application which shows several different kind of devices in a single page and loads external templates depending on the device type.

Users will be able to submit custom templates, so I need to sanitize them.

Currently I'm using ng-repeat with a custom directive to show the devices, which makes use of:

```
template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"></ng-include>'
```

scope.getTemplateUrl() is a function which I declared inside of the directive's link function which returns an URL depending on the device type.

It works flawlessly, but as I said I need to sanitize the URL content.

Unfortunately ng-bind-html wants an expression and not an URL, so the following will not work:

```
template: '<div ng-bind-html="getTemplateUrl()"/></div>'
```

I would like to avoid messing with async operations like $http inside my directive, so I cannot simply get the URL content and I don't know how could I use $sanitize directly without first retrieving the url content.

Comment: check out, [ng-bind-html](http://erikaugust.com/thoughts/ng-bind-html/)

Comment: Did you even read my question? :(

Comment: lol, can you please insert your codes?

Comment: With ng-bind-html it displays "templates/sensorGeneric.html" which is the URL, not the content. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use $sce from ngSanitize module inside your directive function:

```
scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
};
```

Or use a filter to do something like this:

```
ng-bind-html="getTemplateUrl() | sanitizedHtml"
```

More information about sanitize here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: The are two flaws in your answer:
1) You are explicitely trusting a content, but I want the opposite. In fact if I wanted to simply show a trusted content ng-include already does the job. On the contrary the content should *not* be trusted and I want to *sanitize* it.
2) You're working with an expression, while I want to work with an URL.

Comment: Just to be clear I want to sanitize the *content* of my url, in fact the url points to my expression with not-to-be-trusted html.